# Glide - Adding transition crossfade causes placeholder to resize

Tags: android, android-glide

When using Glide with a placeholder and using the transition crossfade, it causes it to have an unwanted resizing effect on the placeholder.

The size of the placeholder should be 50dp inside the layerlist drawable.

With `crossFade()`:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FlCJDSwoAI

Without `crossFade()`:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqZKZb-BKqE

```
Glide.with(context)
      .load(itemList.get(i))
      .apply(RequestOptions.fitCenterTransform())
      .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_altered_placeholder)
      .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
      .into(holder.imageView);
```

Viewholder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vh_iv_album_single_picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The drawable placeholder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- needs the extra spacing otherwise the drawable will be too big -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_black_album_placeholder"
        android:left="51dp" android:right="51dp" android:top="51dp" android:bottom="51dp" />
</layer-list>
```

Is there a fix for this issue?

---

Heres the code to replicate:

MainActivity: https://pastebin.com/3G7BMct3

RecyclerAdapter: https://pastebin.com/eX3T4w9s

Viewholder: https://pastebin.com/Yvri5XFf

Placeholder: https://pastebin.com/pKputgmG

Comment: long story short: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235413/glide-load-drawable-but-dont-scale-placeholder. https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/363. I haven't found a solution for this problem. Also he writes that his pr fixes the issue, but it isn't https://github.com/bumptech/glide/pull/3913

Comment: do you have any hacky solution? I am trying to make it like imgur album load

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't. Otherwise i would have posted it. The only way i see is implementing own transition with `TransitionFactory` but it needs time. Also you may try to contact an author of the pr, probably he knows sth to help

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want your `ImageView` to be resized based on the image that you are loading using Glide, you might consider taking the following approach.

Set a fixed height of your `ImageView` in the layout xml file of `ViewHolder`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vh_iv_album_single_picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also, I would recommend setting the `placeholder` as a part of `RequestOptions`.

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_altered_placeholder);
requestOptions.error(R.drawable.error);
requestOptions.fitCenter();
```

And then apply the options after transition.

```
Glide.with(this)
  .load(itemList.get(i))
  .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
  .apply(requestOptions)
  .into(holder.imageView);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for responding, but I need my image to be resized, so thats why I set my image ```layout_height``` as ```wrap_content``` because if it's a smaller image than the fixed height, there will be white space. Also adding a fixed height DOES NOT fix the transition placeholder resizing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use placeholder. The issue still exists in the latest version of Glide. Instead, I just feed the placeholder drawable into `load` if the actual url is null:

```
Glide.with(context)
      .load(itemList.get(i) ?: R.drawable.ic_altered_placeholder)
      .apply(RequestOptions.fitCenterTransform())
      .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
      .into(holder.imageView);
```